Yocto oe_runmake failed, error in do_bundle_initramfs from bitbake image
I am building yocto image (poky kirksktone release) for x86 target using this set of commands :

./configure.sh -t X86GEN

source os/poky/oe-init-build-env

cd ..

bitbake core-image-integ-x86


Unfortunately, I'm having an error when I run the bitbake build command as you can see on the figures:
Figure #1
Figure #2
Figure #3
I posted the complete stacktrace too:

`ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0 do_bundle_initramfs: oe_runmake failed

ERROR: linux-yocto-rt-5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0 do_bundle_initramfs: ExecutionError('/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488', 1, None, None)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/log.do_bundle_initramfs.3488

Log data follows:

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_bundle_initramfs

| Creating a kernel image with a bundled initramfs...

| Copying initramfs into ./usr ...

| gzip decompressing image

| Finished copy of initramfs into ./usr

| NOTE: KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP: Mon Feb 27 19:19:33 UTC 2023

| NOTE: make CC=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -fuse-ld=bfd -fmacro-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0=/usr/src/debug/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fdebug-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work-shared/genericx86-64/kernel-source=/usr/src/kernel -fdebug-prefix-map=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work-shared/genericx86-64/kernel-build-artifacts=/usr/src/kernel LD=x86_64-poky-linux-ld.bfd  HOSTCC=gcc  HOSTCFLAGS=-isystem/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe HOSTLDFLAGS=-L/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -L/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,--enable-new-dtags                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath-link,/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib                         -Wl,-rpath,/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/lib                         -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 HOSTCPP=gcc  -E HOSTCXX=g++  HOSTCXXFLAGS=-isystem/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe PAHOLE=false bzImage HOST_LIBELF_LIBS=-L/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../../usr/lib/ -lelf CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/linux-genericx86_64-preempt-rt-build/usr/core-image-integ-x86-genericx86-64.cpio

| make: *** No rule to make target 'bzImage'.  Stop.

| ERROR: oe_runmake failed

| WARNING: /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488:306 exit 1 from 'exit 1'

| WARNING: Backtrace (BB generated script):

|       #1: bbfatal_log, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 306

|       #2: die, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 291

|       #3: oe_runmake, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 296

|       #4: kernel_do_compile, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 276

|       #5: do_bundle_initramfs, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 166

|       #6: main, /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/linux-yocto-rt/5.15.96+gitAUTOINC+509f4b9d68_4d335265c1-r0/temp/run.do_bundle_initramfs.3488, line 316

ERROR: Task (/local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/os/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_5.15.bb:do_bundle_initramfs) failed with exit code '1'

NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4522 tasks of which 4521 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:

  /local_data/t0300213/common__integ_os/os/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto-rt_5.15.bb:do_bundle_initramfs

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.`


It was building fine before I modified the bitbake menuconfig because I needed podman to work so I changed some settings in the kernel and then the bitbake build no longer works.
Does anybody have an idea for this? Please help me out here.
If you need more information, I can edit.
Thanks for your help my friends
I'm still learning on yocto and I do not know exactly how to interpret this kind of error.
